# Pandas append different from documentation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I am having trouble using pandas dataframe.append() as it doesn't work the way it is described in the the help(pandas.DataFrame.append), or online in the various sites, blogs, answered questions etc.

This is exactly what I am doing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"0": [0,0,0,0]}, orient="index", columns=["time", "cost", "mult", "class"])
row= [3, 1, 3, 1]
dataset = dataset.append(row, sort=True )
```

Trying to get to this result

```
    time   cost  mult  class
0    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1     1     1     1     1
```

what I am getting instead is

```
    0    class  cost  mult  time
0  NaN    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
0  3.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  1.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  3.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  1.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I have tried all sorts of things, but some examples (online and in documentation) can't be done since .append() doesn't uses anymore the parameter "columns"

> append(self, other, ignore_index: 'bool' = False, verify_integrity:
> 'bool' = False, sort: 'bool' = False) -> 'DataFrame'
>
> Append rows of `other` to the end of caller, returning a new object. other : DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these
> The data to append.
>
> ignore_index : bool, default False
> If True, the resulting axis will be labeled 0, 1, …, n - 1.
>
> verify_integrity : bool, default False
> If True, raise ValueError on creating index with duplicates.
>
> sort : bool, default False
> Sort columns if the columns of `self` and `other` are not aligned.

I have tried all combinations of those parameter but it keeps showing me that crap of new rows with values on a new separated columns, moreover it changes the order of the columns that I defined in the initial dataset. (I have tried also various things with .concat but it still gave similar problems wven with axis=0)

Since even the examples in the documentaition don't show this result while having the same code structure, if anyone could enlighten me on what is happening and why, and how to fix this, it would be great.

In response to the answer, I had already tried

```
row= pd.Series([3, 1, 3, 1])
row = row.to_frame()
dataset = dataset.append(row, ignore_index=True )
     0  class  cost  mult  time
0  NaN    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1  3.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  1.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  3.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4  1.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

alternatively

```
row= pd.Series([3, 1, 3, 1])
dataset = dataset.append(row, ignore_index=True )

   time  cost  mult  class    0    1    2    3
0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  3.0  1.0  3.0  1.0
```

without the ingore_index raises this error in this second case

> TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the
> Series has a name

Answer (score 2):

One option is to just explicitly turn the list into a `pd.Series`:

```
In [46]: dataset.append(pd.Series(row, index=dataset.columns), ignore_index=True)
Out[46]:
   time  cost  mult  class
0     0     0     0      0
1     3     1     3      1
```

You can also do it natively with a `dict`:

```
In [47]: dataset.append(dict(zip(dataset.columns, row)), ignore_index=True)
Out[47]:
   time  cost  mult  class
0     0     0     0      0
1     3     1     3      1
```

The issue you're having is that `other` needs to be a `DataFrame`, a `Series` (or another `dict`-like object), or a list of `DataFrame`s or `Series`es, not a list of integers.

Comment: I don't understand what the index=dataset.columns represents

Comment: It maps the column names to the `Series` index so that the right names match up to the right numbers